# Javascript - load scripts into namespace

Tags: javascript, browser, namespaces

In node.js I have this

```
llcode = fs.readFileSync('./llvm.js/compiler.js', "utf8");
var init_ctx = {process: {cwd: process.cwd,
                        argv: [],
                        stdout: {write: function(x) {}},
                        stderr: {write: function(x) {}}},
              require: require,
              __dirname: llvm_path},
llcompiler = vm.createContext(init_ctx);

vm.runInContext(llcode, llcompiler);
```

Thank to this I can run comands like this:

```
llcompiler.compile(ir);
```

How can I do this in browser?